# How to work remotely under X/vim?

Tags: remote-desktop, nomachine-nx

I've been long fan of NX nomachine for remote desktop, which worked just fine until some time ago.

Recently I have all the time problems with ALT and CAPSLOCK synchronization, and since I am programming under remote X with vim it starts to drive me crazy. I spent more time figuring out what I accidentally deleted, where I've made typo etc than moving forward.

I figured out that the problem appears only when I have lag of > 20ms to the server.
I use ssh tunnel but that's not the problem.

**What are other alternatives to NX which do work for you?**

btw, i am working with 3.4.0-8 NX under Mac and I connect to Linux machine.
Here is the unresolved [bug report](http://www.nomachine.com/tr/view.php?id=TR10H02390).
Greetings.

Comment: Doesn't OS X ship with an X layer?

Comment: I've figured out that starting first X11 under Mac before starting NX client reduces this synchronization issue a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting out X11 under Mac before starting the NX client reduces this problem in a way which makes it possible to work.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use ssh's X11 compression instead of NX? Enable X11 in the remote host's sshd, and do ssh -YC user@remote-host.

Besides, vi/vim is the only editor that can be used on very slow links with long delays. '8j' is much more reliable than pressing the up-arrow key 8 times under such conditions.

Comment: I use nx since it has better performances over ssh X11. By performance I mean the responsiveness.

Comment: Um, not to start an editor war, but there are no conditions under which vi(m) is the only editor that can be used except where it's the only editor installed.

Comment: I've been using vim for more than a decade and I will not switch to anything else because I am happy with it. The problem does not come from the editor but from NX issues. Editor does not have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [xpra](http://xpra.org/), it has a switch for high latency links which prevents keys from getting stuck at the cost of not maintaining an always consistent keyboards state: `xpra --no-keyboard-sync`.
Unlike NX, it does not require an X11 server at the client end and will run natively in OSX.